# HTML pages loading and showing them in .txt file

Tags: java, web-crawler, html-parsing, search-engine

I'm trying to build a search engine in java where i have a folder "crawler" to store downloads but when I open my project and click on that file my computer gets stuck because it tries to load all the urls and texts parsed from the html pages (100k+) and tries to show them in .txt files in the "crawler" folder.

How can I prevent loading and showing them in the file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store your data files somewhere outside of your project. Use e.g. a properties file to store the location to your crawler folder. You should only include such files in your project like source code. Something you would upload to Git or SVN. Not the data files your application operates on. If you would store this data in a database, you wouldn't include the whole database in your project, but only the SQL files to create the tables and views.